reading cell values of excel
private static string GetCellValue(SpreadsheetDocument doc, Cell cell, ref List<ValidationResult> errors)
{
    try{// If the cell does not exist, return an empty string.var result = string.Empty;

            if (cell == null || doc?.WorkbookPart?.SharedStringTablePart?.SharedStringTable == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            if (cell.DataType != null && cell.DataType.Value == CellValues.SharedString)
            {
                var sharedStringTable = doc.WorkbookPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable;
                if (int.TryParse(cell.CellValue?.InnerText, out int index) && index >= 0 && index < sharedStringTable.ChildElements.Count)
                {
                    result = sharedStringTable.ChildElements.GetItem(index).InnerText;
                }
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) && cell.InnerText.Length > 0)
            {
                result = cell.InnerText;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) && cell.CellValue?.InnerText.Length > 0)
            {
                result = cell.CellValue.InnerText;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            errors.Add(new ValidationResult($"Exception in reading cell. {e.Message}"));
            return null;
        }
    }

sometimes the last 2 if statements pick up random ints from the innertext which i assume is formatting. but when i remove those if statements i get complaints that the service isnt reading some cells. wondering on a way to ignore the random ints it reads while still reading values that might be in the innertext due to copying
